# Android sub thread call main thread UI

Tags: android

I am new in Andorid. I want to change the textView in UI. But it will appear the error when sub thread call append. It can be solved by handle and message. But I do not know the mechanism of handle and message in Android. So I ask for others’ help to explain it. thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html)?

It is a lot simpler! Although you have to import the android-support.jar(install Compatibility Library from Android Tools.) and instance the localbroadcastmanager in both threads, I find it a lot easier to read the code afterwards!

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802157/how-to-use-localbroadcastmanager) is an example on StackOverflow (this should be enough for you to get started).

Don't forget to vote up or mark as correct!